# Google Picker with access token

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-api, google-drive-api, google-picker

I'm using `Google Picker` to get files from `Google Drive`.
I will be getting my `Refresh Token` and `Access Token` from my Database.

My old code which is working fine with User Authentication which asks for username and password for the first time.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad"></script>

function onGoogleApiLoad() {
        gapi.load('auth', { 'callback': onGoogleAuthApiLoad });
        gapi.load('picker');
    }

function onGoogleAuthApiLoad() {
        window.gapi.auth.authorize({
            'client_id': 'MY_CLIENT_ID',
            'scope': ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
        }, handleAuthResult);
    }

var oGoogleauthToken;
    function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
        if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
            debugger;
            oGoogleauthToken = authResult.access_token;
            createGooglePicker();
        }
    }
```

Now, I'm trying to open the Picker using the Access token by the following code because I don't want to ask for User Authentication any more.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad"></script>

var oGoogleauthToken = MY_TOKEN_FROM_DATABASE;
createGooglePicker();

function createGooglePicker() {
        debugger;        
        var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
            .addView(new google.picker.DocsView())
            .setOAuthToken(oGoogleauthToken)
            .setDeveloperKey('MY_DEVELOPER_KEY')
            .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
            .setCallback(GooglepickerCallback)
            .build();
        picker.setVisible(true);
    }
```

But I'm getting an error like google is not defined.

Is there any way, I can do this?
Is there any thing, I need to do in the script reference file?

Comment: You need to get new tokens every time. Access tokens are ephemeral, so they will expire. Refresh tokens won't expire (though keep in mind there's a limit to them, so a user may lose their refresh token eventually). I'm not sure if `setOAuthToken` takes refresh tokens though.

Comment: `But I'm getting an error like google is not defined` please be specific about the errors you are getting.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?